# Berkeley DB java edition, any LGPL or BSD alternatives in Java?

Tags: database, nosql, b-tree, berkeley-db-je

I am dealing with a huge dataset consisting of key-value pairs. The queries are always in the form of range queries on the key space (keys are numbers) hence any persistent B-Tree like structure will handle the situation. I would like to use BDB-Java Edition but the product is closed source and my company doesn't want to buy BDB-JE License. I am wondering, would you please share your experience with any non-GPL java based key-value storage system.

Thanks,
-A

Comment: There is also a question related to BDB JE licensing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132839/what-should-i-really-release-as-open-source-when-i-use-berkeley-db-je

Answer (score 2):

There is also [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/), which is a document database written in Java and can be embedded to application (no external server) like BDB Java edition. They use [Apache 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028156/any-open-source-software-using-orient-db-database-have-you-any-experiences-with)  license.

They also have key/value based variant: [OrientKV](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orient-kv.htm). I haven't really used Orient myself, just poking around, so I don't know if it supports your use case (range queries on key space).  However, it advertises itself as really fast.

Though, it seems Orient DB is not very widely used. I even made a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028156/any-open-source-software-using-orient-db-database-have-you-any-experiences-with) asking if anybody has any experiences to share.

Answer (score 1):

[Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/) comes to mind as a very fast KV store which is under the LGPL and is embedded like the BDB and supports BTrees. It is c-based but a javaclient is available and I had no trouble installing it.

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) nice , but it runs as a separate server. Again Java support is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I should emphasize, we are looking for pure-java implementations (we are shipping a desktop application written totally in java).

Comment: There is also JDBM which is pure java : http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/

There is a page with projects using it : http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/JDBM-Powered.html