# Any Open Source software using Orient DB database? Have you any experiences with that database?

Tags: java, nosql, orientdb

Do you know any open source software that uses [Orient DB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/)?  Or have you used that product yourself? Any experiences to share?

I have recently looked into Orient DB, and it has nice and interesting feature set (fast, embeddable in Java, simple API) but it seems that it is not widely used. Is it just because the Orient DB is a new player on the field?

Comment: Never heard of it. YADB (Yet another DB). Maybe it is the best thing since sliced bread, I will wait until I hear ripples through the channels.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After the total failure of ODBMS (at least from an adoption point of view), it seems obvious to me that the NoSQL movement is perceived by (ex) ODBMS players (like Versant, db4o, Orient) as an opportunity for a resurrection.

This IMHO exactly the case of OrientDB which is the result of the rewrite of the Orient ODBMS engine as a document oriented database (in other words, re-branded to fit in the NoSQL niche market).

But while OrientDB benefits from the experience acquired in the ODBMS field (the author has more 10+ years of experience in this field and is member of the JDO expert group, how surprising), I'm not aware of any projects/customers using it (and I believe they would publish some testimonials if they had many of them). Some possible reaons:

1. The product is new.
2. Only a **very few people** might need a NoSQL solution.

The conjunction of both points means you won't see "mass adoption". At least, this is my opinion.

That being said, I agree that OrientDB looks interesting.

Comment: OrientDB is a brand new product born as document-graph dbms. My experience in ODBMS has been fundamental to know how to create a very fast storage layer, but the two products are totally different. About adoption there are many companies are using it in production. Here some of them: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Production_deployments but look at the public Group to meet all the 600 subscribers.